# Run different code based type

Tags: c#

I want to call a method for my WPF-App with subtype objects of my *Piece* class. My problem is that the subtype objects have more properties than e.g the the *Text* objects.

Do you know a way to cope with this better than I do in my *FillForm* example?

```
namespace Namespace
{
    public abstract class Piece
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }

        }

        public class Text : Piece
        {

        }

        public class Image: Piece{
             public string filePath { get; set; }
            public string fileformat { get; set; }
        }

        public class Video : Image
        {

        }   
    }
}
```

Example method:

```
public void FillForm(Piece currentPiece)
{    
            pieceIdTextBox.Text = currentPiece.id.ToString();
            pieceNameTextBox.Text = currentPiece.title;
            pieceDescriptionTextBox.Text = currentPiece.description;
            if (!currentPiece.GetType().ToString().Equals("Namespace.Text"))
            {
                pieceFileSelectURLTextBlock.Text = (currentPiece as Namespace.Image).filePath;
                SetPreviews((currentPiece as Namespace.Image).filePath);
            }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: No idea what you are actually using this for, but usually if a certain inherited type is supposed to behave differently you put that code **inside** of that class (abstract or virtual method). What are you trying to do? What's your end-goal?

Comment: what about polymorphisme? https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism

Comment: *"My problem is that the subtype objects got more properties than e.g the the Text objects. Do you know a way to coupe with this better than I do in my FillForm example?"* Just a stab in the dark here, but are you asking how to **cast** or how to handle multiple derived types? Because that `currentPiece.GetType().ToString().Equals("Namespace.Text")` could easily be replaced with `if(currentPiece is Text text)`.

Comment: I want to build a backend for a virtual exhibition. The data model will be shared with a Unity project. So I dont want to put to much dependencies into it.

Comment: I still don't understand why you check for `Text` and then cast to `Image`.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer because `Image` got alle the properties I need and `Text` is the only subtype I want to exclude for now.

Comment: @FrankHsnblg You are still trying to describe you attempted solution, not the actual problem. When I asked *"What are you trying to do?"* I did not mean *"**How** are you trying to solve it?"*, I meant *"**What** are you trying to solve"*.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer srry, I'm trying find a generic way to fill my form based on the type of my object.

Comment: @FrankHsnblg So the form contains fields for all properties of all types, regardless of wether they are used or not? What's the purpose of the form and what other fields are there? I'm just trying to establish a bit of context here - In programming there are usually many ways to do things which is why context is very important. Depending on what you are trying to do the right answer might be to change not how you do things but also what you do and expand the scope of the question.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Yes. Currently I'm switching the visibility of the parts of the form as the type needs it.

Comment: @FrankHsnblg Then I'd go with Jehof's approach, unless you can't use C#7 in Unity then use zaitsman's one (it's identical but uses older mechanisms).

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a safecast:

```
public void FillForm(Piece currentPiece)
{    
            pieceIdTextBox.Text = currentPiece.id.ToString();
            pieceNameTextBox.Text = currentPiece.title;
            pieceDescriptionTextBox.Text = currentPiece.description;

            var imagePiece = currentPiece as Image;
            if(imagePiece != null)
                pieceFileSelectURLTextBlock.Text = imagePiece .filePath;
                SetPreviews(imagePiece .filePath);
            }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just change the method to the following with more type-safety

```
public void FillForm(Piece currentPiece)
{    
    pieceIdTextBox.Text = currentPiece.id.ToString();
    pieceNameTextBox.Text = currentPiece.title;
    pieceDescriptionTextBox.Text = currentPiece.description;
    if (currentPiece as Namespace.Image imagePiece)
    {
        pieceFileSelectURLTextBlock.Text = imagePiece.filePath;
        SetPreviews(imagePiece.filePath);
    }
}
```